# Probabilities of bivariates

Tags: probability, bivariate-distributions

[image]

$$ ( ≥\frac12|  ≥\frac12)
$$

¿is it correct using the intervals 1/2 to infinity?

I don´t get it

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is it that you'd like to know whether it is correct? $P(X\geq 1/2|Y\geq 1/2)$ is just a number.

Comment: I need the process of doing this, using double integrals

Comment: I am asking if the answer is integrating with the interval 1/2 to inf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P[X>\frac{1}{2}|Y>\frac{1}{2}]=\frac{\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}dx \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{3}{2}y^2 dy}{\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}3y^2dy}=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^2\frac{1}{2} dx=P[X>\frac{1}{2}]=0.75$$

This because X,Y are independent

Comment: did you get the marginal?

Comment: Yes. It's the integrand in the denominator

Comment: How did you get it?

Comment: 1.5 The answer could be greater than 1?

Comment: I obviuosly forgot the X density in the integral.  It's An obviuos typo that you could have fixed by yourself! Now it is fixed

Comment: @rosita galixx : is it clear now?

Comment: Totally clear... Thank you